# PyCharm custom Git repository

Tags: git, github, pycharm

is it possible to configure `PyCharm` with `Git` repositories hosted by services other than `Github`? Looks like PyCharm allows only to configure Github as a service within it's preferences.

Comment: See this self-answered question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348093/pycharm-github-push-failed-fatal-authentication-failed

Answer (score 0):

What PyCharm are you using?

I use community edition 3.1.1 and it works.

You have to select "Check out from version control -> Git" from the "New Project" menu.

You can then clone a repository using a link that **usually** looks like "git@[SITE]:[PROJECT].git".

Just checked with [codebasehq](http://www.codebasehq.com) and it works.

Comment: I have the 3.1.2 Pro edition and. It's true that you can clone from a remote repo. But how to add a remote repo to an already existing project?