# fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push one of my projects to github, and I keep getting this error:

```
peeplesoft@jane3:~/846156 (master) $ git push

fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

     git push --set-upstream origin master
```

So I tried it and got this:

```
peeplesoft@jane3:~/846156 (master) $ git push --set-upstream origin master

fatal: Authentication failed
```

Another stackoverflow thread suggested I try the following, with disappointing results.

```
peeplesoft@jane3:~/846156 (master) $ git push -u origin master

fatal: Authentication failed
```

Then I tried this:

```
peeplesoft@jane3:~/846156 (master) $ git config remote.origin.push HEAD

peeplesoft@jane3:~/846156 (master) $ git push

fatal: Authentication failed
```

Any hints?

Comment: The repo must exist at github _before_ you can push to it. Does it? And is the repo you're working with a clone of it?

Comment: I cloned the repo from Github then added 1 line to a readme file and then tried to push it back.

Comment: i was getting the same error because i forgot to commit the files

Comment: -u and --set-upstream are same

Comment: This is an alias that solve: `git push || $(git push 2>&1 | grep "." | tail -1)`

Comment: I my case, our url directory changed result in this

Answer (score 228, accepted):

You fixed the push, but, independently of that push issue (which I explained in "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)": `git push -u origin master` or `git push -u origin --all`), you need now to resolve the authentication issue.

That depends on your url (ssh as in '`git@github.com/yourRepo`, or https as in `https://github.com/You/YourRepo`)

For https url:

If your account is protected by the [two-factor authentication](https://github.com/blog/1614-two-factor-authentication), your regular password won't work (for https url), [as explained here](https://superuser.com/a/647862/141) [or here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21027728/6309).

Same problem if your password contains special character (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22512390/6309))

If https doesn't work (because you don't want to generate a secondary key, a PAT: personal Access Token), then you can switch to ssh, [as I have shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17671315/6309).

---

As noted by [qwerty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/985454/qwerty) in the comments, you can automatically create the branch of same name on the remote with:

```
git push -u origin head
```

Why?

- HEAD (see your `.git\HEAD` file) has the refspec of the currently checked out branch (for example: `ref: refs/heads/master`)
- the default [push policy](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushdefault) is **[simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6547682/6309)**

Since the refpec used for this push is head: (no destination), a missing `:<dst>` means to update the same ref as the `<src>` (head, which is a branch).

That won't work if [HEAD is detached](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309) though.

---

Or you can use [Git 2.37 (Q3 2022)  and the new global option `push.autoSetupRemote`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401899/6309):

```
git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true
git push
```

Comment: If you are on any branch, this is useful `git push origin head -u`. Automatically creates the branch of same name on the remote.

Comment: @VonC Can you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64480132/how-to-authenticate-github-on-ubuntu-git-credential-netrc-is-not-a-git-comma

Answer (score 148):

Also you can use the following command:

```
git push -u origin master
```

This creates (-u) another branch in your remote repo. Once the authentication using ssh is done that is.

Comment: This is really relevant to the problem, since the issue is with authentication. He's also stated that he already tried that in his post.

Comment: I downvoted for 2 reasons. 1st one: the OP stated that he already tried this. 2nd one: `-u` option is the shortcut for the `--set-upstream` option which has nothing to do with the creation of a new branch. From the [documentation of the `-u` or `--set-upstream` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--u): "For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less git-pull[1] and other commands.". Actually I don't get why this answer got upvoted that much as it is misleading.

Answer (score 97):

If you define the action `git push` it should take it if no refspec is given on the command line, no refspec is configured in the remote, and no refspec is implied by any of the options given on the command line.

Just do it:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

then

```
git push
```

Comment: You need to be aware that this does changes to your global git settings, which may have some adverse effects. But this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Mavamaarten what are the potential adverse effects?

Comment: @kosii Literally what it does: to always push a local branch to upstream. It is my default way of work as I see no harm creating new branches upstream 99% of the time, but it may not be true for other people.

Answer (score 52):

Apparently you also get this error message when you forget the `--all` parameter when pushing for the first time. I wrote

```
git push -u origin
```

which gave this error, it should have been

```
git push -u origin --all
```

Oh how I love these copy-paste errors ...

Comment: Thanks. I was getting this error in Visual Studio Code and this worked, but in the context of multiple developers can somebody explain what this did?

Answer (score 24):

Please try this scenario

```
git push -f --set-upstream origin master
```

Comment: You should provide more explanation on how and why this works.

Comment: "not bad" is a really bad explanation for anything. "not bad" makes your answer really bad.

Comment: This does nothing to address the error OP mentioned: "Authentication failed"

Comment: Yes. It did work for me. I think this is forcing  the commit to upstream (remote) branch.

Comment: **WARNING** Do not do this. `-f` stands for force, and you should never force push your master branch without knowing what it does -- this will possibly throw away commits on the remote server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer brother, i have tried all the other answers of this questions but only this one worked... Thank you soo much

Answer (score 20):

use this command first before you push in to the branch

```sh
git config --global push.default current
```

After executing the above command use git push command.

Comment: the first one worked. the second one didn't. hmmm

Answer (score 18):

**You need to configure the remote first, then push.**

```
git remote add origin url-to-your-repo
```

[Actual Instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/)

Answer (score 17):

It means that you don't have your branch(the branch that you want to push) in your remote repository, in other words it does not exist in your remote repository(it wasn't created yet)...
So use this Code:

```
git push -u origin 'your branch name'
```

this code will create your branch in your remote repository and will push it...

Comment: Simple and cleaner way of sorting the issue Thanks @jamal

Comment: What is the behavior if you make this call and the remote branch does exist?  Does it just revert back to a normal push?

Answer (score 12):

on a very simple side, once you have other branches, you can't just use for pushing a branch

```
git push
```

But you need to specify the branch now, even if you have checkout the branch you want to push, so

```
git push origin <feature_branch>
```

Where  can be even the `master` branch

Answer (score 10):

Well, I was having the same trouble while uploading and I resolved it by 
doing the same thing which it says to do:
Earlier I was trying to push through terminal to my repository in linux by https
like

```
git push https://github.com/SiddharthChoudhary/ClientServerCloudComputing.git
```

But was not getting any result and hence I went down deeper and tried:

```
git push --set-upstream https://github.com/SiddharthChoudhary/ClientServerCloudComputing.git master
```

And it worked. Thus then you will get prompted with username and password. 
I also **generated a token** and instead of Password I pasted the token and thus, being done successfully.

1. To generate a token go to your Github account and in Developer Settings and then create another token.
2. After getting that, copy
       that token and paste in the password prompt when it's been asked.

Comment: You made my day! SIde note: using `SSH` i.e. `git@github.com/SiddharthChoudhary/ClientServerCloudComputing.git` should also work too, without the user credentials, if SSH authentication is set-up already.

Comment: EPIC WIN MY FRIEND!

Answer (score 7):

I made the simple error of forgetting to commit:

```
git commit -m "first commit"
```

then `git push origin master` worked.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem

[image]

I resolved it that used below command

```
$ git branch --set-upstream develop origin/develop
```

and it will add a config in the config file in the .git folder.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. I used the master branch both locally and remotely, so I wrote this: 
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
Git complained -set-upstream is getting deprecated, but replacing it with --set-upstream-to should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

First use `git pull origin your_branch_name` 
Then `use git push origin your_branch_name`

Comment: Sorry If this sounds silly. How to get to know my branch name. My repo is in AWS.

Comment: Use "git branch"

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple solution to this which worked for me on macOS Sierra.
I did these two commands:

```
git pull --rebase git_url(Ex: https://github.com/username/reponame.git)
git push origin master
```

If it shows any fatal error regarding upstream after any future push then simply run :

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Answer (score 4):

If you constantly get the following git error message after attempting a git push with a new local branch:

> fatal: The current branch  has no upstream branch.

To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

```
git push --set-upstream origin <branchname>
```

Then the issue is that you have not configured git to always create new branches on the remote from local ones.

The permanent fix if you always want to just create that new branch on the remote to mirror and track your local branch is:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

*Now you can git push without any errors!*

https://vancelucas.com/blog/how-to-fix-git-fatal-the-current-branch-has-no-upstream-branch/

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error because I was trying to push the code without `write` access, I only had `read` access.
In Bitbucket, you can check access on the right side when you open your repo (Repository details) :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was because I had deleted the hidden **.git** folder.

I fixed it by deleting the folder, re-cloning, and re-making the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at `.git/config` file, It should look like:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/blueray453/log-opened-file-paths.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

**Authentication failed** means **Authentication failed**. Please make sure you have the **correct access rights** and the **repository exists**.

Look at `[remote "origin"]`. Are you using the right url? Does it start with `https` or `git@github.com`? Those two use different authentication procedure. If you are using wrong url then **remove the `[remote "origin"]` section** and run:

```
git remote add origin <right-url>
```

If `[branch "master"]` or `[branch "main"]` or whatever is missing, run:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

or,

```
git push -u origin master
```

For simplicity, I will remove both `[remote "origin"]` and `[branch "master"]` section and then to push an existing repository from the command line:

```
git remote add origin <right-url>
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

If you have followed [Git asks for username every time I push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64935725/1772898), then from now on only `git push` will be enough.

Comment: this worked for me.
git remote add origin <right-url>
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main

Comment: The last three lines are the answer actually. rest of it is in keeping with the spirit of “teach a man to fish...”.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** A computer and your github associated. Use SSH. Computer code so you do not need to submit verified [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5CVQ.png)

**2.** git can not manage empty folder. So you have to write such a readme.md saved in a file. Otherwise you will not find the file.

**3.** Your local project is nothing new projects move over. Please

`git init`

`git remote add origin +"githublink"`

`git add .`

`git commit -m ""` go again.

**4.** then `git pull origin master` (the key)

**5.** At last `git push origin master` (solve all problem).

http://my.oschina.net/psuyun/blog/123005 参考链接

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to push your code direct to the master branch then use command

```
git push origin master
```

It helps me.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error.I think it was because I clone it and try to push back.
     **$ git push -u origin master**
This is the right command.Try that

Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 691 bytes | 46.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.

- [new branch]      master -> master
  Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.

  ```
  It was successful. Try to create new u branch
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the cause was that I forgot to specify the branch

```
git push myorigin feature/23082018_my-feature_eb
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was pushing the changes to a private repo to which I didn't had the write access.
Make sure you have the valid access rights while performing push or pull operations.

You can directly verify via

Comment: "Directly verify via" what?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on any branch, you can use this:

```
git push origin head -u
```

This will automatically create new branch of the same name on the remote.

Answer (score 0):

commit your code using

```
git commit -m "first commit"
```

then config your mail id using

```
git config user.email "example@example.com"
```

this is work for me

Answer (score 0):

The thing that helped me:
I saw that the connection between my directory to git wasn't established -
so I did again:
`git push -u origin main`

Answer (score 0):

Different case with same error (backing up to external drive), the issue was that I'd set up the remote repo with clone. Works every time if you set the remote repo up with bare initially

```
cd F:/backups/dir
git init --bare
cd C:/working/dir
git remote add backup F:/backups/dir
git push backup master
```

Answer (score 0):

In my mind, this is just a wrong default git behavior.
Having reviewed all options support by git, also reviewed the relevant git code:

https://github.com/git/git/blob/140045821aa78da3a80a7d7c8f707b955e1ab40d/builtin/push.c#L188

The best solution I would suggest it simply override the push default command:

```
git config --global alias.pu 'push -u'
```

This basically changes the default behavior of push so that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered just about the same problem, but not from the master branch.
I tried to push two (2) branches to my remote repository, by using the `$ git push` command; which unfortunately threw up the:

```
fatal: The current branch <branch-name> has no upstream branch. To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

 git push --set-upstream origin <branch-name>
```

I got it fixed with this command below:

```
$ git push -u origin --all
```

PS: The solution provided here should, i believe, make it easier for git to track out branches remotely; this could come in-handy someday, when working on projects with couple of branches.

Comment: Seeing this mentioned upfront in [VonC's 2014 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23402125): Does your answer add something?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a local branch called Master, whereas master is on Github.
I simply rename my Master -> master and checkout to master.
And then push it. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is better, Clone this repo newly. Maybe it just lost track.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this issue, while checking out the code from `git` itself, u need to give the command like below:

`git checkout -b branchname origin/branchname`

Here, by default we are setting `the upstream branch`, so you will not be facing the mentioned issue.

Answer (score -1):

For me the problem come from the name of my branch : "#name-of-my-branch", without "#" it's work fine!