# Git- Repository error during push code on a specific branch, remote: Repository not found

Tags: github, gitlab

i have a branch name salil_dev in my current repository. i want to push code on this branch and when i am running command: `git push --set-upstream origin salil_dev`
I got error of

```
fatal: The current branch salil_dev has no upstream branch.
```

I checked my login credentials and all are upto date, but still am facing this problem. Please correct me where am doing wrong.

Comment: I posted a few suggestions below. Please let me know if this solves your problem. If not, we can keep digging.

Comment: Is this a brand new repo you're setting up? Are you pushing to gitlab or github?

Comment: no it's not a brand new repo, and I am pushing to github

Comment: Can you please update your question with the response from `git remote -v`? Only keep the relevant lines that relate to `salil_dev` and `master`. Also, in GitHub, can you see all your files in the master branch? In the branches drop-down menu, do you see `salil_dev`?

Comment: i can't put the name of my current repo on here due to some reasons. But i recently create a new repo and trying to put some other random code, and again i got the same issue.

Comment: You can hide the name of the repo. I just want to make sure there is an origin remote defined with (push).

Answer (score 0):

A few things come to mind:

1. Make sure you are checked in to your local `salil_dev` branch when you run this command
2. If this is a new branch and you don't need to change the upstream branch, just call `git push origin salil_dev`
3. Is this a new repo? If so try calling `git remote add origin url-to-your-repo` to add a new remote to your repo.

If that doesn't work, try this:

1. `origin` is the default remote name, but it may be different. Run `git remote -v` to show a list of all remotes and make sure `origin` is in the list with `(push)` listed next to `origin`.
2. If this is a new repo, first run `git push -u origin master` (with local master checked out), followed by the push to your feature branch (with that branch checked out). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/5752730) for more details.
3. You tagged your question with `github` and `gitlab`. Make sure you're pushing your commit to the correct repo.
4. If you're using https, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23402125/5752730) for additional suggestions related to authentication issues.

Comment: yes, I have checked into the salil_dev branch before run this command. I also run git push origin salil_dev but still got the same error. When I run git remote add origin url-to-your-repo command then I got fatal: remote origin already exists. The issue is still the same.

Comment: yes, I tried everything which you mentioned in your edited answer, but still, the issue is the same.