# How to authenticate Github on Ubuntu? git: 'credential-netrc' is not a git command

Tags: git, gnupg, .netrc

I read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/647829/pushing-a-local-repo-to-a-github-repo-which-has-dual-factor-authentication/647862#647862) and I have checked my credentials,still I can not git push.

```
 git push --set-upstream origin master
git: 'credential-netrc' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

What I have done so far:

1. Created ~/.netrc
2. `gpg --gen-key`
3. `gpg -e -r myemail@gmail.com ~/.netrc`
4. Added creation helper by coping [Perl repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/credential/netrc/git-credential-netrc.perl) to `~/.local/bin/git-credential-netrc`
5. Set up Git

git config --global credential.helper "netrc -f ~/.netrc.gpg -v"

6. Editeed ~.profile according to [this](https://bryanwweber.com/writing/personal/2016/01/01/how-to-set-up-an-encrypted-netrc-file-with-gpg-for-github-2fa-access/) link.

git config shows

```
file:/home/milenko/.gitconfig   user.email=milenko.markovic@gmail.com
file:/home/milenko/.gitconfig   credential.helper=netrc -f ~/.netrc.gpg -v
file:.git/config        core.repositoryformatversion=0
file:.git/config        core.filemode=true
file:.git/config        core.bare=false
file:.git/config        core.logallrefupdates=true
file:.git/config        remote.origin.url=https://github.com/MilenkoM/blog_mongo
file:.git/config        remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

It seems that my creation helper is not recognized. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that:

- `~/.local/bin/` is in your $PATH
- `git-credential-netrc` is executable (`chmod 755 ~/.local/bin/git-credential-netrc`)

Then you can test if `git credential-netrc` (note the space) will respond anything (even if it errors)

Comment: I forgot to change the permissions.

Comment: @RichardRublev Yes, I forgot to change them as well too many time for other git command utilities, so now I am at least aware of that step.