# Fatal errors on git push (no upstream branch, pack exceeds maximum allowed size,write error: Broken pipeB/s, )

Tags: github, push, fatal-error, git-push

I have an old repository on Github (the last commit was 2 years ago). Recently I worked with the local copy, and performed several commits, tried to push, it gave me the following error

```
$git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

I searched for a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401652/fatal-the-current-branch-master-has-no-upstream-branch) , I tried `$ git push --set-upstream origin master`the following errors occurred:

```
Enumerating objects: 182, done.
Counting objects: 100% (182/182), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (110/110), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (166/166), 2.44 GiB | 599.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 166 (delta 61), reused 147 (delta 47), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I tried another solution from [the same post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401652/fatal-the-current-branch-master-has-no-upstream-branch) `$ git push -u origin head`
it gives me some extra errors

```
git push -u origin master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.112.4' to the list of known hosts.
Enumerating objects: 182, done.
Counting objects: 100% (182/182), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (110/110), done.
remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipeB/s
error: remote unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To github.com:drnesr/PrayerTimesStudies.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (failed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:AcountName/RepoName.git'
```

How can I solve this push to GitHub problem?

Comment: I have the same exact problem. I increased the http.postBuffer feature and moreover I also had the http.sslVerify to false from git config. Nothing of those two features made it worked.

Comment: I tried a lot of solutions but no luck too!

Comment: What I did was to buy a UTP Cable Cat6, my problem was after all resolved. It might seem kind of weird but oftentimes when you are using git with a Wifi connection, this type of error persists as the HTTP connection gets weakened and therefore is unable to send packages to the other side. Thus, aborting the connection. If you are on Wifi, trust me,you should maybe use an Ethernet cable. It worked miraculously for me :)

Comment: Thank you for thinking out of the box, I will try it soon and give you a feedback